# Which member in PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS structure gives the current used memory

Tags: c++, c, windows

Following is the PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS structure

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS {
  DWORD  cb;
  DWORD  PageFaultCount;
  SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
  SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
  SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
} PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS, *PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;
```

Which member of the structure gives the current used memory of the specific process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure member

```
WorkingSetSize
```

gives the current used memory.

> The working set is the amount of memory physically mapped to the
>   process context at a given time.

Ref.:[Process Memory Usage Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).