# Obtaining accurate heap usage in Windows (for debugging memory leaks in a single process)

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-leaks

I've worked for years as an embedded SW developer, in which memory leaks (even minimal amounts of memory) were often really critical.

In these environments usually it was possible to evaluate the amount of used heap, and this made possible at least a rudimentary/rough memory-leak debugging just by printing the total amount of used memory in key points of the code.

Now I'm developing a C++ parser in Windows environment and... surprisingly I cannot find a way to trace this basic information. So the question is: how can I do that?

Before answering let me say that for some reasons **I'm not interested in Valgrind-like tools**.

Before asking a new question I've read a lot of previous questions, such as:

[How to get memory usage under Windows in C++](http://How%20to%20get%20memory%20usage%20under%20Windows%20in%20C++)

[Which member in PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS structure gives the current used memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896469/which-member-in-process-memory-counters-structure-gives-the-current-used-memory)

[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

But none of them provided a solution suitable for my needs. So I decided to write a new question in which to make clear **(1)** what I exactly need and **(2)** the attempts I already made trying to achieve my goal.

For this reason, below I provide a minimal example program in which I perform some 128kB (0x20000 bytes) allocations (in different ways) and then I perform the corresponding memory release. After each step, I call a `debugMemory()` utility that prints every field of `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#define ONE_K 1024

static void debugMemory( const char * header )
{
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;

  if( header )
  {
    printf("%s:\t\tGetProcessMemoryInfo() returned %d\n", header, GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*)&pmc, sizeof(pmc)));
  
    printf("%s:\tPageFaultCount\t\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",         header, pmc.PageFaultCount, pmc.PageFaultCount);
    printf("%s:\tPeakWorkingSetSize\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",       header, pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize, pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize);
    printf("%s:\tWorkingSetSize\t\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",         header, pmc.WorkingSetSize, pmc.WorkingSetSize);
    printf("%s:\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",  header, pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage, pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage);
    printf("%s:\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",      header, pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage, pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage);
    printf("%s:\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage\t= %d 0x%08X\n", header, pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage, pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage);
    printf("%s:\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",   header, pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage, pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage);
    printf("%s:\tPagefileUsage\t\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",          header, pmc.PagefileUsage, pmc.PagefileUsage);
    printf("%s:\tPeakPagefileUsage\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n",        header, pmc.PeakPagefileUsage, pmc.PeakPagefileUsage);

    printf( "%s:\tPrivateUsage\t\t\t= %d 0x%08X\n", header, pmc.PrivateUsage, pmc.PrivateUsage );
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  /* Initial */
  debugMemory("INI");
  Sleep(5000);

  /* Malloc */
  char *p1 = (char *) malloc(128 * ONE_K);
  debugMemory("MALLOC");
  Sleep(5000);

  /* New */
  char *p2 = new char[128 * ONE_K];
  debugMemory("NEW");
  Sleep(5000);

  /* Free */
  free( p1 );
  debugMemory("FREE");
  Sleep(5000);

  /* Delete */
  delete[] p2;
  debugMemory("DELETE");
  
  return 0;
}
```

According to most answers to SO questions, fields `WorkingSetSize` and `PrivateUsage` were the best candidates for providing the information I need. Anyway, just to provide a complete scenario, I post the results for all of them:

```
INI:            GetProcessMemoryInfo() returned 1
INI:    PageFaultCount                  = 766 0x000002FE
INI:    PeakWorkingSetSize              = 2834432 0x002B4000
INI:    WorkingSetSize                  = 2830336 0x002B3000
INI:    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage         = 22448 0x000057B0
INI:    QuotaPagedPoolUsage             = 22448 0x000057B0
INI:    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage      = 4864 0x000057B0
INI:    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage          = 4480 0x00001180
INI:    PagefileUsage                   = 1069056 0x00105000
INI:    PeakPagefileUsage               = 1069056 0x00105000
INI:    PrivateUsage                    = 1069056 0x00105000
MALLOC:         GetProcessMemoryInfo() returned 1
MALLOC: PageFaultCount                  = 794 0x0000031A
MALLOC: PeakWorkingSetSize              = 2949120 0x002D0000
MALLOC: WorkingSetSize                  = 2945024 0x002CF000
MALLOC: QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage         = 22448 0x000057B0
MALLOC: QuotaPagedPoolUsage             = 22448 0x000057B0
MALLOC: QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage      = 4864 0x000057B0
MALLOC: QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage          = 4480 0x00001180
MALLOC: PagefileUsage                   = 1204224 0x00126000
MALLOC: PeakPagefileUsage               = 1204224 0x00126000
MALLOC: PrivateUsage                    = 1204224 0x00126000
NEW:            GetProcessMemoryInfo() returned 1
NEW:    PageFaultCount                  = 797 0x0000031D
NEW:    PeakWorkingSetSize              = 2961408 0x002D3000
NEW:    WorkingSetSize                  = 2957312 0x002D2000
NEW:    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage         = 22448 0x000057B0
NEW:    QuotaPagedPoolUsage             = 22448 0x000057B0
NEW:    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage      = 4864 0x000057B0
NEW:    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage          = 4480 0x00001180
NEW:    PagefileUsage                   = 1339392 0x00147000
NEW:    PeakPagefileUsage               = 1339392 0x00147000
NEW:    PrivateUsage                    = 1339392 0x00147000
FREE:           GetProcessMemoryInfo() returned 1
FREE:   PageFaultCount                  = 797 0x0000031D
FREE:   PeakWorkingSetSize              = 2961408 0x002D3000
FREE:   WorkingSetSize                  = 2957312 0x002D2000
FREE:   QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage         = 22448 0x000057B0
FREE:   QuotaPagedPoolUsage             = 22448 0x000057B0
FREE:   QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage      = 4864 0x000057B0
FREE:   QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage          = 4480 0x00001180
FREE:   PagefileUsage                   = 1339392 0x00147000
FREE:   PeakPagefileUsage               = 1339392 0x00147000
FREE:   PrivateUsage                    = 1339392 0x00147000
DELETE:         GetProcessMemoryInfo() returned 1
DELETE: PageFaultCount                  = 797 0x0000031D
DELETE: PeakWorkingSetSize              = 2961408 0x002D3000
DELETE: WorkingSetSize                  = 2957312 0x002D2000
DELETE: QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage         = 22448 0x000057B0
DELETE: QuotaPagedPoolUsage             = 22448 0x000057B0
DELETE: QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage      = 4864 0x000057B0
DELETE: QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage          = 4480 0x00001180
DELETE: PagefileUsage                   = 1339392 0x00147000
DELETE: PeakPagefileUsage               = 1339392 0x00147000
DELETE: PrivateUsage                    = 1339392 0x00147000
```

Let's summarize what we can understand from these results:

- `PrivateUsage` seems to be the field I'm searching for: after every allocation its value is 0x21000 bigger (instead of 0x20000. But I can forgive those 0x1000 bytes of overhead)
- Its value **ISN'T** reduced after memory deallocations **(!!!)**
- I would have expected that unused virtual memory was given back to the OS after a certain amount of time (that's why I tried the insertion of 5s sleeps after each step) but it seems that I was wrong
- `WorkingSetSize` seems toto grow after every allocation, as well, but the amount of the grouth is inconsistent as far as I can understand

Any help would be really appreciated. I'm open both to any *magic* function I wasn't able to find (to obtain the accurate amount of heap usage) and to any workaround trick (for example something forcing used virtual memory shown by `PrivateUsage` to be updated).

Comment: You may like [Heaptrack](https://www.kdab.com/heaptrack-v1-1-0-release/).

Comment: @JesperJuhl , thanks for your comment. After a fast read of your link it seems that it is a *valgrind-like* tool, that unfortunately doens't fit my needs, and furthermore it seems to be designed for Linux. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. Just thought I would mention it as you *might* find it useful. Just trying to help.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. ;)

Comment: *Maybe* [ETW](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oanapl/2009/08/04/etw-event-tracing-for-windows-what-it-is-and-useful-tools/) is closer to what you are looking for..?

Comment: [WPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer) is also worth a look.

Comment: FWIW, I believe that Windows manages memory in terms of pages, so memory dedicated to your app will always be a multiple of the page size. This would account for some of the 0x1000 "overhead" you are seeing. Some of this that due to quantization and is not real overhead might be used for future, smaller allocations. Such smaller allocations would show on change in memory usage reported by Windows. I believe you can't get what you want from the OS, you will need to instrument your code.

Comment: Also, as I recall, older C++ runtime library dynamic memory implementations used memory suballocators and retained memory freed by the program for future use, not returning it to the OS. When windows improved  its memory allocation handling, I understand that run time library implementations stopped doing this. I do not know for certain that this practice no longer occurs at all in modern implementations.

Comment: Oops, I meant : Such smaller allocations would NOT show as a change in memory usage reported by Windows.

Comment: I just don't understand why you *don't* want to use Valgrind-like tools.

Comment: @ssbssa Because _I can't_. I need a programmatical accurate evaluation of the used heap that is also able to trace values in production code. Open to any solution. :)

Comment: Suggest trying methodology based on hooking allocations/frees. Maintain your own current heap usage measure. Example is Visual C++ _CrtSetAllocHook in _DEBUG builds only

Comment: "I would have expected that unused virtual memory was given back to the OS after a certain amount of time" What would be the point? It's not like the OS can use it for anything since each process has its own VM space and that would just require the process to ask the OS for more later if it needs more.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand it, even if it's strange a system in which the memory occupation of a process (even VM) can only increase and never decrease! After 5 months this is still an open task, though secondary. As soon as priorities will allow it I'll probably explore the global overloading of new/delete (I'm still poor in C++)

Comment: I'm sorry, @WilliamClements! I actually "lost" your comment. I'm forced to use Embarcadero, in which `_CrtSetAllocHook` is defined dummy. There's actually _Codeguard_, but it seems it's not mantained anymore by borland and it brings a lot of side problems. Among them , it is not suitable for the feature in production version (capable to be enabled at runtime) that I would like to develop.

Answer (score 0):

PrivateUsage is a perfectly acceptable metric for what you seem to be trying to do.

The reason you get 0x21000 rather than 0x20000 is because the allocation has a header before the address returned by malloc or new (to allow that allocation to be freed properly) there is nothing already in memory to satisfy the request, and the underlying operating system call to get more memory for the process ultimately returns things in multiples of pages, so it has to round up to a multiple of the page size.

The reason the value of PrivateUsage doesn't go down during your test is likely because the buffer in question is being saved to satisfy future requests.  To verify this guess you can just duplicate your sections that do new and free, so that you have a "NEW2" report and a "FREE2" report.  I would expect that the output for "NEW2" is the same, with respect to PrivateUsage, as the output for "FREE".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The _"0x21000 rather than 0x20000"_ is not the issue, as in the question itself I actually state that the over**head** is probably due to the heap header. Unfortunately, the `PrivateUsage` value isn't enough for me (the question is indeed about that value not satisfying my needs) and I either would like a way to _dismiss_ the memory _"being saved to satisfy future requests"_ or to read the actual virutal memory used by my process.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "memory used by my process"?

Comment: You are right. It means nothing. What I need is simply the accurate count of the memory allocated with malloc/new from the heap, reflecting any `free` performed in the meanwhile. I'm confident it is clear in my question (starting from the title).

Comment: The reason, as explained in the question, is providing a metric for memory leak detection in production applications running months in which Valgrind-like tool cannot be used.

Comment: On the Linux side, I can point you to such a tool (which just requires one to take a live core of the process) but the variant of that tool for Windows is not in the public domain.

Comment: I think it only works on the "debug" heap, but you probably want something from
#include <crtdbg.h>
int _CrtMemDifference(
   _CrtMemState *stateDiff,
   const _CrtMemState *oldState,
   const _CrtMemState *newState
);
// etc